# how to generate a rails app without javascript?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

My homework is to generate a rails app without use javascript, is it possible?i tried to delete all .js files and node_modules after i generate with `rails new $appname` but i got an error every time, can someone help-me?

Comment: What error did you get?

Comment: We want to see your effort toward solving this if it's homework. "[How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/128421)", '[ask]" and the linked pages and "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)"
will help.

Answer (score 8):

When creating your new app, you can skip various components you don't need. Among those components are all JavaScript files. You can thus create your app with:

```
rails new $appname --skip-javascript
```

Please refer to the output of `rails new --help` for other supported options.